# How can I export a 3D character, including its animation?

Tags: animation, export, import

I'm new to Blender. I want to insert character animation in a live-action video.

I downloaded a simple rigged 3D figure, and created a keyframe animation. Now, what I'd like to do is to *export* that short animation sequence, so I can insert it into my motion-tracked video.

Now, how can I **export** then **import** that animated figure coughing, and then insert it into the video and duplicate it?

EDIT: Problem solved. I KNEW this was a simple fix.. All I needed to do was to save the file, then go into the file (that I wanted to IMPORT the animation into), then use "append" to import the object from that Blender file. It kept the animation and model intact, and now I have the little dude coughing on my 3D tracked video! huzzah.

Comment: If you are using Blender for animation the character, and the motion tracking is also in Blender, what use is the importing and exporting going to be?

Comment: @Leander Sorry, I knew this was a bonehead question. As I edited above, I solved by Saving -> Appending. Thanks for the response in any case!